# ViewController issue in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am fairly new to Xcode, but I have run into a bit of a problem. I have a tabbed view controller, and one subtab has a UITableView. On cell click, I need TableData (a ViewController) to open up. For some reason, I just get a black screen. I then changed my code to this:

```
TableData *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableData"];
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but I get an error SIGABRT in Xcode. How do I fix this?

This works, but gives me a black screen:

```
TableData *view = [TableData alloc];
view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController: view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an identifier for the segue inside the storyboard and then use:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourTableViewStoryboardSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

UPDATE:

Problem was most likely due to user grabbing an invalid row from his tableView. In order to just grab the row number all you need to do is:

```
int rowNumberSelected = indexPath.row;
```

As for his second code snippet, the reason its only showing a black screen is because he is not actually linking it to his viewController in the storyboard. He is simply just allocating the code. If he added subviews through the code, then they would show up but nothing from the storyboard.

Since the user is using Storyboard, its always better to just use segues and dismissals however.

Comment: did u create a modal segue between the viewController your currently on and the tableViewController u want to go to?

Comment: Go into your storyboard. Ensure the viewController you are trying to segue from is highlighted. Hold down the control button and click-drag from the name of that viewController onto the viewController in the storyboard that you are trying to move to. Choose modal segue when you are asked to select. Then click on the circular thing on the center of the line between the two viewControllers (that line is the segue). In the right hand pane you will be able to name the identifier for that segue. That "identifier" is the one you must put in your code

Comment: is the one that your going to embedded in a navigation controller or something? Does the sigabort give you error text?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22725/discussion-between-elite-gamer-and-ttarules)